# Issue with social.Login against Deezer

Tags: codenameone

I'm facing a weird behavior using com.codename1.io.Oauth2 and com.codename1.social.Login against Deezer.  While Deezer uses the argument 'app_id' in place of 'client_id', it still accepts the request with the required args.

-> URL Request expected by deezer:
https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&perms=basic_access

Code to match it as much as possible:

```
@Override
protected Oauth2 createOauth2() {
    Hashtable<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    params.put("app_id", APPLICATION_ID);
    params.put("perms", "basic_access");

    return new Oauth2(OAUTH_URL, APPLICATION_ID, REDIRECT_URL, null, null, null, params);
}
```

-> URL finally sent to deezer:
https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&response_type=token&app_id=APP_ID&perms=basic_access

This brings the browser up fine and displays the Deezer login screen after a redirect to login.php+args.  It's fine so far.  However, once I enter the userid/password, it does a redirect to the login.php again with no args.  This is weird as it seems to work fine when I test the URL from Firefox or Safari.  Any idea to help me out?  Why is the behavior different?

Also, I guess it would be a good idea to make Oauth2 implement an interface used by Login rather, no?  Or at least make the Oauth2.buildURL() protected.

Thanks a lot.

E

Comment: I have no idea but is it possible that a CORS attack is detected incorrectly because the page is embedded in the client?

Comment: Hello Shai, tx for the answer.  I may be going the wrong path but I enabled javax.net.debug on the Simulator and watched network traffic on Firefox to compare and I see that the Simulator is missing two POSTs : one to google recaptcha and a second to deezer (where I see the reCaptchaToken in the header).  I carry on searching but if you have an idea, that'd be cool.

Comment: I'm guessing the captcha is missing so deezer rejects the post, do you see the captcha UI on the device?

Comment: Hello Shai,
Thanks for answering.  No, the captcha does not appear on the Simulator screen where as it appears in the lower right corner on Firefox.  How can I see why it's loaded on the JavaFX browser?

Comment: If you run it on a device does it show? If you resize the UI in the desktop to a mobile size can you see the captcha?